# "Pattern not found" message on found and highlighted pattern in vim

Tags: vim, text-processing

I have a fair number of PHP classes source files that I can list using the command `grep -r "class " *` with each file containing the `class <MyClass>` pattern.

For example, one such file contains:

```
<?php

class NavlinkItem {

  var $id;
  var $name;
  var $description;
  var $image;
  var $imageOver;
  var $url;
  var $blankTarget;
  var $language;
  var $templateModelId;
  var $navlinkId;

  function NavlinkItem($id = '') {
  }
```

I would like to replace the `function NavlinkItem` pattern by the `function __construct` pattern.

The `NavlinkItem` pattern can be derived from the actual name of the `system/navlink/NavlinkItem.php` source file and I can get the it with `expand('%:t:r')`

I can store the `NavlinkItem` pattern in an `a` register `let @a = expand('%:t:r')`

I want to do a replace on  the content of that register:

```
execute 's/function ' . getreg('a') . '/function __construct/'
```

The pattern seems to be found as it is highlighted in yellow.

But the command still errors and shows the `E486: Pattern not found: function NavlinkItem` message.

Comment: Does this solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289278/7264739

Comment: There is only one instance of the pattern in each file, so the % character is of no use here... wait !! My mistake ! That was what I thought about commenting at first, but then I tried adding the % character to my command anyway just to see what would happen. And it did the replace all right ! Spot on ! You may provide an actual solution here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `%` symbol at the start of the regex if the whole document should be searched, rather than just the current line.

So `execute '%s/function ' . getreg('a') . '/function __construct/'` should work.